# Why can't I get full web page content when using `curl` command?

Tags: html, web, curl

I have a web link from browser https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195. It has many images and property information. However, when I use `curl https://www.onthehouse.com.au/property-for-rent/vic/aspendale-gardens-3195` command, I got this response:

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=30&xinfo=5-7476759-0%200NNN%20RT%281591511174218%200%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%284%2c315%2c0%29%20U18&incident_id=312000140010082884-36761776158147461&edet=12&cinfo=04000000&rpinfo=0" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 312000140010082884-36761776158147461</iframe></body></html>
```

I wonder why I can't get the same content as web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out curl Documentation [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Curl does not work like a web-browser. Web browsers send multiple requests like Cookies,pragma etc. 
Also, URL syntax is based on Protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP etc) so it does not return what you expect as curl can not perform nested tasks.

You can also see the documentation of Curl on you distro.
`man curl`

This is the header for Stackoverflow sent from my browser/

````
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 180
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241704/why-cant-i-get-full-web-page-content-when-using-curl-command
Cookie: acct=t=SXdti%2bPF7J0IXT6RqwhKexQJ6AAtJks5&s=aLgrXO9L5h5YgXRbW2YplLoc%2fQKYcfOj; prov=c6550cb5-5096-590c-1b8a-0e97a0e2cc0a; _ga=GA1.2.44496431.1588150861; __qca=P0-790627570-1588150861560; __gads=ID=a972e5a85d0c4e72:T=1588150862:S=ALNI_MbPmS2oeBPAmuYh3K26FtPg1igB1g; sgt=id=e16c6c4c-5cc2-466e-9064-9b78720c16de; _gid=GA1.2.490713082.1591334234
TE: Trailers```
````